# append adding contents to first list item, not adding new items to list

Tags: python

```
def gen(filename):
    result=[]
    with open(filename) as sample:
        for line in sample.read().splitlines():
            for ch in line.split():                
                result.append(ch)
                yield ch
return result
```

If i pass in "ABCDEF", i get ["ABCDEF"] back in result, instead of ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]

What could be the problem?

Also, am i using the generator correctly? If not, what am i doing wrong? I am close to grasping the concept, but i am not quite there yet and feel that adding a list might be making the generator counterproductive

EDIT: Here is how i am opening the file:

```
with filled_filename("ABCDEF") as fn:
        self.assertEqual(list(project.gen(f)), ["A","B","C","D","E","F"])
        print(list(project.gen(ff)))
```

Comment: It's not a question of whether it's "adding commas", but as to whether it's appending to the list, or appending to the string that's the first element of the list.

Comment: The commas are just syntax used to display the list -- they aren't actually included inside it as contents.

Comment: that said, the obvious answer is to use `for ch in line`, not `for ch in line.split()`; `split()` splits on whitespace, and your line *has* no whitespace.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The actual issue is that he's appending "ABCDEF" instead of appending "A" followed by "B", etc. So it's not that things are being appended to the first item in the list... it's that he never split things into characters to begin with.

Comment: @smarx, yes, see my other comment (posted... 20 seconds, apparently? before yours). But the original title displayed a major misunderstanding of how data structures work, which is what I was trying to address.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, comments crossed. :-) I was responding to your initial comment.

Comment: I'm so close to getting it smarx!! Your code works, but not on files that span multiple lines

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
def gen(filename):
    with open(filename) as sample:
        for line in sample.read().splitlines():
            for ch in line:
                yield ch

# Example usage:
for ch in gen('myfile.txt'):
    print("Got character '{}'.".format(ch))
```

As you said, the `list` you're building up sort of makes the generator redundant. (You're `yield`ing each character as you go, but you're also returning the complete `list`, which is a pattern I've never seen before and probably not what you want to do.)

The main issue with your code, though, is that I think you want to split a line into individual characters, but `line.split()` doesn't do that. Just use `for ch in line`.

**EDIT**

Trying to get somewhere closer to your code:

```
def gen(filename):
    with open(filename) as sample:
        for line in sample:
            line = line.rstrip()
            for ch in line:
                yield ch

def filled_filename(text):
    with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(text)
    return 'test.txt'

filename = filled_filename(b'ABCDEF')
assert list(gen(filename)) == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

This code works and passes the assert.

Comment: Well my teacher is using test cases (as i added in my edit). And That's the output that i am getting with those test cases

Comment: @Team.Coco I'm not sure if you're asking a question, clarifying something, saying that my answer works for you, or saying that it doesn't. :-) Does my code do what you want?

Comment: I am getting a not implemented error because the genertor isnt returning anything for some reason

Comment: Can you share your current code and the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Did you see what i added as a sample test case?

Comment: Yes. The test case is broken in a handful of ways... `fn` is never used, `f` isn't defined, and neither is `ff`.

Comment: (I also have no idea what `filled_filename` does, though I can take a guess from context.)

Comment: @Team.Coco See my edit for an attempt to use the code the same way you're using it.

Comment: I'm sorry for lack of a lot of code, but i am doing this as an assignment and my instructor says its okay to ask questions here, but you need to modify it so that other students in the class cannot find and use your code. Anyways what you wrote works, except that it is adding a few extra characters as white spaces (' '), what could be the problem?

Comment: The test file can span multiple lines and have as many white spaces as it wants, so maybe thats where the problem rests?

Comment: So basically it is not working on files that span multiple lines

Comment: @Team.Coco You haven't said what you actually want to do. I guessed based on your code and what you were expecting that you want to put every character (excluding newlines) into a list. It sounds now like you don't want spaces to go into the list. Is that it? Is the requirement "Put every character other than `'\n'` and `' '` into the list?"